# Linux C code crashes

Tags: c, linux, crash, beagleboneblack, spi

I wrote a C program on the Beaglebone Black to read and write to the 25LC256 (EEPROM). I am able to compile it without any errors or warnings, `gcc SPI.c -o SPI`, but when I try running it `./SPI`, my entire Beaglebone stops working, and I have to reboot it. In fact, the program doesn't even output anything. I have the code print out "Starting" at the begging, but that doesn't even work.

Could anybody see where I might be going wrong ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//You need to correctly identify the SPI device bus and number
int write64NVM(int fd, unsigned char data[], int length, unsigned int add);
int read64NVM(int fd, unsigned char to[], int length, unsigned int add);

static const char *device = "/dev/spidev1.0";

int main(){

    uint8_t mode=0, bits=8;
    uint32_t speed=500000;
    int file;

    printf("Starting");

    if ((file = open(device, O_RDWR))<0){

        perror("SPI: Can't open device.");
        return -1;

    }

    if (ioctl(file, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE, &mode)==-1){

        perror("SPI: Can't set SPI mode.");
        return -1;

    }

    if (ioctl(file, SPI_IOC_RD_MODE, &mode)==-1){

        perror("SPI: Can't get SPI mode.");
        return -1;

    }

    if (ioctl(file, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits)==-1){

        perror("SPI: Can't set bits per word.");
        return -1;

    }

    if (ioctl(file, SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits)==-1){

        perror("SPI: Can't get bits per word.");
        return -1;

    }

    if(ioctl(file, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed)==-1){

        perror("SPI: Can't set max speed HZ");
        return -1;
    }

    if (ioctl(file, SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed)==-1){

        perror("SPI: Can't get max speed HZ.");
        return -1;

    }
        printf("spi mode: 0x%xn", mode);
        printf("bits per word: %dn", bits);
        printf("max speed: %d Hz (%d KHz)n", speed, speed/1000);
        // sending one byte on the MOSI line and receiving the data on MISO


        write64NVM(file, "hello", 6, 0);

        close(file);



        return 0;

    }


int write64NVM(int fd, unsigned char data[], int length, unsigned int add)

{


    unsigned char InstructionBuffer[1], AddressBuffer[3];

    int status;

    //DataBuffer = (char *) malloc(length);

    struct spi_ioc_transfer xfer[3];

    InstructionBuffer[0] = 6; //Set the write enable latch (enable write operations)
    AddressBuffer[0] = 2; //Write data to memory array beginning at selected address
    AddressBuffer[1] =  (add >> 8); 
    AddressBuffer[2] =  (add & 0b11111111);
    //DataBuffer = data;

    //First Transaction
    xfer[0].tx_buf = (unsigned long)InstructionBuffer;
    xfer[0].rx_buf = (unsigned long)NULL;
    xfer[0].len = 1;
    xfer[0].cs_change = 1;

    //Second transaction
    xfer[1].tx_buf = (unsigned long)AddressBuffer;
    xfer[1].rx_buf = (unsigned long)NULL;
    xfer[1].len = 3;
    xfer[1].cs_change = 0;

    //Third transaction
    xfer[2].tx_buf = (unsigned long)data;
    xfer[2].rx_buf = (unsigned long)NULL;
    xfer[2].len = length;
    xfer[2].cs_change = 1; 

    status = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(3), &xfer);
    if (status < 0)
    {

        perror("SPI_IOC_MESSAGE error");
        return;

    }


    return status;

}

int read64NVM(int fd, unsigned char to[], int length, unsigned int add){

    //Read Sequence :

    //Pull ~CS low
    //The 8-bit instruction is transmited to EEPROM followed
    //by 16-bit address, with first MSB of the address being a 'dont care'
    //bit. 

    //According to Page 7 Figure 2-1 of the 25LC256.pdf, to read an address from
    //EEPROM, the BBB must only send out 2 transactions. The instruction and the address.
    //In this case, the instruction is read, so the value of transaction is 3.
    //~CS apears to be kept low throughout the entire transaction until data 
    //has completely been shifted out of EEPROM.

    //Like in write64NVM, there are 3 buffers
    //unsigned char InstructionBuffer, AddressBuffer[3], DataBuffer[8], 
    //but the latter  will be used to store the Data recieved.

    unsigned char InstructionBuffer, AddressBuffer[2], *DataBuffer;

    int status;

    //DataBuffer = (char *) malloc(length);


    struct spi_ioc_transfer xfer[3];

    InstructionBuffer = 3; //Read intruction value
    //AddressBuffer[0] = 2;
    AddressBuffer[0] = add >> 8;
    AddressBuffer[1] = add & 0b11111111;
    DataBuffer = 0;

    //First Transaction
    xfer[0].tx_buf = (unsigned long)&InstructionBuffer;
    xfer[0].rx_buf = (unsigned long)NULL;
    xfer[0].len = 1;
    xfer[0].cs_change = 1;

    //Second transaction
    xfer[1].tx_buf = (unsigned long)AddressBuffer;
    xfer[1].rx_buf = (unsigned long)NULL;
    xfer[1].len = 2;
    xfer[1].cs_change = 0;

    //Third transaction
    xfer[2].tx_buf = (unsigned long)NULL;
    xfer[2].rx_buf = (unsigned long)to;
    xfer[2].len = length;
    xfer[2].cs_change = 1;

    status = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(3), &xfer);
    if (status < 0)
    {

        perror("SPI_IOC_MESSAGE error");
        return;

    }


    return status;



}
```

Please forgive my poor coding, I'm still a beginner.

Comment: Try adding `fflush(stdout);` after `printf("Starting");` to force what you want to be printed be printed.

Comment: Ok, thanks ! Now It successfully prints out "starting", but still the code freezes. Even when  I do ctrl+C or ctrl+X (I never remember which), the code doesnt stop. I have to manually reboot the device.

Comment: Since you fixed that, maybe fix the rest of your output lines as well. All those trailing `n` are somewhat useless. Perhaps `\n` was the intention? And maybe instrument debug output into `write64NVM` and `read64NVM` as well?

Comment: Good idea, I added fflush(stdout); to other places, and I noticed that the code gets stuck inside the write function (write64NVM). I also changed the n to \n but that didn't change anything noticeable.

Comment: Using `'\n'` would alleviate the need for `fflush`-ing everywhere, but that's not really important right now. It would seem your setup for your write operation is not playing well with your device. That probably needs the brunt of your attention now.

Comment: Good idea, Ill try fixing the setup. Thanks